# RegEx test from JavaScript to Java

Tags: javascript, java, regex

I'm trying to migrate the following algorithm from an angular service into the backend, thus from JavaScript to Java.

Can you help me get to the same result in Java as I do in js?

```
var UA                  = navigator.userAgent,
    isIOS               = /ip(hone|od|ad)/i.test(UA),
    isSafari            = /(mac os x).*version\/\d(.\d)+ (mobile\/\w{5,} )?safari/i.test(UA),
    isSafari5           = /(mac os x).*version\/5[.\d]+ (mobile\/\w{5} )?safari/i.test(UA),
    isAndroid           = /android/i.test(UA),
    isAndroidBrowser    = isAndroid && !/chrome|firefox/i.test(UA),
    isAndroidBrowserOld = isAndroidBrowser && parseFloat(/android ([\d\.]+)/i.exec(UA).pop()) < 4.3,
    isAndroid2          = isAndroidBrowser && /android 2\.\d/i.test(UA),
    isAndroidChrome     = isAndroid && /chrome/i.test(UA),
    isKindleFire        = /KF[A-Z]{2,3}/.test(UA),
    isFirefox           = /firefox/i.test(UA),
    isIE11              = /Trident/i.test(UA),
    isIE                = /msie \d/i.test(UA) || isIE11,
    isMSTouch           = (navigator.maxTouchPoints > 0) || (navigator.msMaxTouchPoints > 0),
    isMSTouchPrefix     = !!navigator.msMaxTouchPoints,
    isPhone             = ((/mobile/i.test(UA) && !/ipad|tablet/i.test(UA)) || matchMedia('only screen and (max-device-width : 767px)').matches) && !isKindleFire,
    isTablet            = (isAndroid && !isPhone) || (isIOS && !isPhone) || isKindleFire,
    isMobile            = isPhone || isTablet;

    this.isPhone = isPhone;
    this.isTablet = isTablet;
```

Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: use some online tool..if you understand the regex, you won't have any problem in translating it

Comment: I think you know how to do it, you're just lazy to do it yourself..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general

- Regexes can be used using java.util.regex.Pattern, Java has no language level support for them like JavaScript
- Remove the // around the regex, this is part of the JavaScript regex integration
- any \ will need escaping as \\ within Java strings
- /i insensitive is equivalent to Pattern.compile(regex, Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE)
- Core regex should be same in 99% of cases

Example

```
String UA = "iphone";

boolean isIOS = 
        Pattern.compile("ip(hone|od|ad)", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE).matcher(UA).matches();
boolean isSafari5 = 
        Pattern.compile("(mac os x).*version\\/\\d(.\\d)+ (mobile\\/\\w{5,} )?safari", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE).matcher(UA).matches();

System.out.println(isIOS);
```